# @font face is not working

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am trying to add Futura web font to my webpage but when i add this to a independent css file which named fonts.css

```
@font-face {
   font-family: futura;
   src: url('/fonts/Futura LT Bold.ttf')
}
```

Then i added this to my main css file :

```
h1{
  font-family: futura;
}
```

But the font does not change when i explore my files with web inspector(firefox) i see that the font family is sat to futura but when i check for the font i get this  :

But futura is not like that (serif font) my files hierarchy is like this

- Root folder

  - Page.htm
  - JS

    - Java.js
  - css

    - fonts.css
    - style.css
  - fonts

    - Futura LT Book.ttf
    - Futura LT Light.ttf

What might be wrong ?

### Update :

I use firefox

Comment: can you place `ttf` file inside css folder

Comment: no need check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe your font file have a problem and it is not for web.
you can use one of the online convertor like http://www.font2web.com/ to convert the font to all font format files and use css below for your font-face implementation

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: 'Conv_FREESCPT';
    src: url('fonts/FREESCPT.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('fonts/FREESCPT.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/FREESCPT.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/FREESCPT.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

### replace:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: futura;
   src: url('/fonts/Futura LT Bold.ttf')
}
```

### with:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: futura;
   src: url("../fonts/Futura LT Bold.ttf")
}
```

Comment: @Abdou no need to change thi location of `ttf` files place it in font folder and try now made some changes

Answer (score 0):

I think you need double period (..) on your src, which means you go up one folder and then look for the folder behind the slash. For example:
src: url('../fonts/Futura LT Bold.ttf')

Another problem could be that your browser might not support . ttf font-files, you need to add .eot.